# S2Member Wordpress Plugin Configuration

Tags: wordpress

Hi I am a newbie in Wordpress.

I want a registration form and paypal button in a page.

User will fill in the details and click the paypal payment button .

The user information gets saved and the url will be redirected to the paypal website for

payment.

I have installed the s2member plugin ,read the configurations but somehow unable to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TO ANSWER NEED YOU TO CONFIRM WHETHER you will need different access levels, will you want any free users BEFOR paying and your subscription model.  no point using sledge hammer to crack a nut user registration and payment can just be setup with Gravity forms and PayPal but need to know more to answer properly.

Let us know and can then help .

Comment: This is what i got the reply from client.There will be no access levels.


"This page will be where people can sign up to the 2013 PuntPal Newsletter and UFTipping Competition.
There will be a Contact Form, a PayPal pay button and UFT Bank Account Details for Bank-to-Bank Transfer."